# Websocket does not connect on refresh

Tags: javascript, php, websocket

I have got a Websocket server using Ratchet/PHP:

```
<?php
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use MyApp\Mediator;

$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            new Mediator()
        )
    ),
    9000
);

$server->run();
?>
```

Mediator class:

```
<?php
namespace MyApp;
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

class Mediator implements MessageComponentInterface {
    protected $clients = [];

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        $this->clients[$conn->resourceId] = $conn;
        echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
        echo "Incoming: $msg\n";
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        unset($this->clients[$conn->resourceId]);
        echo "Connection {$conn->resourceId} has disconnected\n";
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
        echo "An error has occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n";
        $conn->close();
    }
}
?>
```

Now on the client side, I have this basic JS code:

```
let ws = new WebSocket('wss://localhost:8443');
ws.addEventListener('open', () => {
    ws.send('Hello!');
});
ws.addEventListener('message', event => {
    alert(event.data);
});
```

It does work (I can send and receive messages), however here's the problem:

When visiting the page for the first time, a connection with the websocket server is established and works fine. When I close the page, the connection is closed (as it should). However, when I refresh the page the connection is closed (on unloading the page, this is normal) but when the page is loaded again, no connection is made to the websocket server. I have to refresh *again* to make the script connect. This should not happen, right? I have no idea why this is happening, what's causing this.

Comment: Looks like a kind of a bug in a browser or there is an error. I would also make an error listener on a websocket. There is a chance that the socket connection itself cannot be established by some error.

Comment: Also just found out no connection at all is made in Firefox, not sure if that has anything to do with this. As I can connect in Chrome, in the DevTools no error messages are showing when it doesn't connect. So I will try the error listener

Comment: There is also a `Network` tab in Chrome where you can see all connections that are made after opening the console. So open this and refresh site then try to check what's going on there

Comment: how do you start the socketserver ?

Comment: @Sergey when the connection is working, it shows 101 status code. When I refresh (and thus not connecting) the status stays at 'pending'.

Comment: @FatFreddy `> php server.php`, also Nginx is setup as reverse proxy but I'm pretty sure this is not part of the problem as it still exists without nginx.

Comment: So it looks like there is some problem on the server side because the client has tried to establish the connection but by some reason the server didn't respond on that

Comment: I'm not so sure, with different servers the same problem occurs. I tried C++ and Node solutions to a websocket server and they work, apart from the problem described.

Answer (score 0):

maybe add an event listener to close your `ws` javascript `WebSocket` before trying to reopen it.

```
let ws = new WebSocket('wss://localhost:8443');
ws.addEventListener('open', () => {
    ws.send('Hello!');
});


$(window).unload(function () {
   ws.close();
});
```

also include possible console errors, as this looks like a issue with your javascript `WebSocket` logic, but I have been reading [more info about Rachet/PHP](http://socketo.me/docs/connections) and I would appreciate additional information on your backend logic.

## Update

I suggest you [to check out their demo page](http://socketo.me/demo) and debug both your code and your network requests. Start re-creating a 1-1 exactly identical working functionality, then implement your changes and understand what causes your errors:

1) Review your network request and persist the log, read them and report any strange issues

[image]

2) Review their code for the demo

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: I'm still looking over the code, I noticed they use Autobahn in the demo so I'm going to try to do that as well. What I noticed so far is in the demo the server response with a Sec-WebSocketProtocol (set to _wamp_) which I am missing. I don't think this is an issue, as the connection never reaches the server.

Comment: @Scamtex yes I read the sourcecode. On the js side I noticed inside `socket.me/vendor/web-socket.js` that they use `window.Websocket = MozWebSocket` for firefox, but I believe there is no need as `WebSocket` should be compatible with Firefox. Their example is not good, they do not provide you a full working example, this example is built with `flask` and it is over-engineered. They have several examples at https://github.com/cboden/Ratchet-examples/tree/master/src so you may want to fork then and try them out